# How can I update a div every 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Hi I would need to update a div every 15 seconds. I tried to do it using jQuery.
I then inserted the jQuery file at the top of the page and wrote this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#stats").load("stats.php");
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#stats").load('stats.php?randval='+ Math.random());
  }, 15000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
<div id="stats"></div>
```

I noticed that this script worked correctly on a blank page, but by entering 'prototype.js' the script stopped working.

Comment: By entering `prototype.js`? Perhaps your issue lies with that?

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need for Prototype.js in the same page, then consider rewriting your periodical update function to use that RATHER than jQuery. Working around the conflict is just adding two libraries to the page that both do the very same thing.

```
<script>
$(document).observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('stats', 'stats.php', { frequency: 15 });
});
</script>
<div id="stats"></div>
```

Done, and I have to say, more elegantly than the stock jQuery Ajax stuff. This automatically backs off the frequency of requests if the result does not change, saving you bandwidth. Once the result is different than the last time, it returns to the schedule again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try referencing jquery with its full name (jQuery) instead of $

Or run the noConflict command https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Or create a namespace in which jQuery will be assigned to $ safely

```
(function($){
   // use $ here

})(jQuery)
```